# add or subtract timezone difference to javascript Date

Tags: javascript, date

What is the best approach to add or subtract timezone differences to the `targetTime` variable below. The GMT timezone values comes from the DB in this format: `1.00` for London time, `-8.00` for Pacific time and so on.

Code looks like this:

```
date = "September 21, 2011 00:00:00";
targetTime = new Date(date);
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can use Date.getTimezoneOffset which returns the local offset from GMT in minutes.  Note that it returns the value with the opposite sign you might expect.  So GMT-5 is 300 and GMT+1 is -60.

```
var date = "September 21, 2011 00:00:00";
var targetTime = new Date(date);
var timeZoneFromDB = -7.00; //time zone value from database
//get the timezone offset from local time in minutes
var tzDifference = timeZoneFromDB * 60 + targetTime.getTimezoneOffset();
//convert the offset to milliseconds, add to targetTime, and make a new Date
var offsetTime = new Date(targetTime.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: this would be correct but what if it is daylight saving time in your country and now if your GMT was say +2, it would now be +1

Comment: getTimezoneOffset accounts for daylight savings time.  I am in the U.S. Eastern time zone, which is normally GMT-5, but GMT-4 in daylight savings.  If I call getTimezoneOffset in my browser right now, I get 240, which is GMT-4.  That, of course, only handles daylight savings for local time.  The timezone offset from the DB should be adjusted for DST on the back end.

Answer (score 36):

Simple function that works for me:

```
adjustForTimezone(date:Date):Date{
    var timeOffsetInMS:number = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + timeOffsetInMS);
    return date
}
```

Comment: it worked for me. but small changes on 3rd line
`date.setTime(date.getTime() + timeOffsetInMS);` add `+` instead of  `-`

Answer (score 20):

If you need to compensate the timezone I would recommend the following snippet:

```
var dt = new Date('2018-07-05')
dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + dt.getTimezoneOffset())
console.log(dt)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

> The getTimezoneOffset() method returns the difference, in minutes, between a date as evaluated in the UTC time zone, and the same date as evaluated in the local time zone.

So all you need is to compensate, IN MINUTES

Comment: I needed to get it back into a date so wrapped line 2 in new Date, i.e. `new Date(dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + dt.getTimezoneOffset()))`

Comment: Although for me the plus needed to be a minus. Brain not quite working as to why exactly.

Answer (score 3):

This example shows how to use the local datetime but format it as ISO:

```
const d = new Date();

let dtOffset = new Date(d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset()));
// Date in EST and ISO format: "2021-11-30T15:33:32.222Z"
console.log(dtOffset.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Typescript version of @alexp answer

```js
     adjustForTimezone(d:Date, offset:number):Date{
        var date = d.toISOString();
        var targetTime = new Date(date);
        var timeZoneFromDB = offset; //time zone value from database
        //get the timezone offset from local time in minutes
        var tzDifference = timeZoneFromDB * 60 + targetTime.getTimezoneOffset();
        //convert the offset to milliseconds, add to targetTime, and make a new Date
        var offsetTime = new Date(targetTime.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 * 1000);
        return offsetTime;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adjustForTimezone(date){    
      var targetTime = new Date(date);
      // Manually construct a UTC date string to ensure time components are set consistently
      // This avoids timezone and DST issues entirely
      return new Date(Date.UTC(targetTime.getFullYear(), targetTime.getMonth(), targetTime.getDate()));
}
```