# Incorrect date shown in new Date() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

[image]

This is what I get in chrome console. I pass "2016-09-05"(YYYY-MM-DD) as the date and it shows me Sept 4,2016 as the date.

Another constructor shows the right date

[image]

Passing it comma separated needs some tokenizing + parsing + making month zero indexed which I want to avoid

Comment: Try "new Date("2016-05-09") " instead.

Comment: That gives me "Sun May 08 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"

Comment: No @Kadaj - the syntax for the `Date` constructor is correct: `new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]])`

Comment: The result seems correct. You are at UTC -4

Comment: Hint: it's to do with the timezone that it's using - i.e. `GMT-0400` - so it's taking 4 hours from the `00:00` on that day (taking you to the previous one) - check the timezone your browser is using...

Comment: You *can* specify to use a time created from UTC - `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))` (minute and second are optional)

Comment: @GeoffJames Just a complement: the values for `month` are 0, 1, 2 ... 11

Comment: @cezar - I was wrong in last comment, so deleted it to prevent confusion (whoops, my bad). When you use the ctor as per my previous comment, yes - it does use `0-based` index. The ctor the OP is using is a string, so this will parse correctly. In this instance, if the OP were to use the ctor I've posted above - it would need to be `new Date(Date.UTC(2016,08,05));` or `new Date(2016,08,05);`

Comment: OK @Robin. Your post tags `datepicker`, but your question is referring to the console in Chrome (I'm not questioning the parsing of the date, by the way). Are you actually using a `datepicker`? If so, what is your HTML code? What are you trying to achieve? Since you've edited your post, you mention that you'd want to avoid using 0-based index to parse the date etc. Is this coming from a date-picker? You need to add the scope to which you're having the issue and your desired outcome.

Comment: Another question that might help you with the timezone offset issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403486/add-or-subtract-timezone-difference-to-javascript-date

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you omit the time in the `new Date(string)` constructor, UTC time is assumed. So the displayed value is actually correct. Use `new Date('2016-09-05T00:00')` to create the date object in local time.

Edit: while some browsers seem to support the `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` format, it's not officially supported, and, as mentioned in the comments, this doesn't work in Safari. I've updated the answer to use a `T` instead of a space between date and time.

Per the [ECMAScript® 2023 Language Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format):

> Date-only forms:
>
> - YYYY
> - YYYY-MM
> - YYYY-MM-DD
>
> It also includes “date-time” forms that consist of one of the above
> date-only forms immediately followed by one of the following time
> forms with an optional UTC offset representation appended:
>
> - THH:mm
> - THH:mm:ss
> - THH:mm:ss.sss

Comment: Nice answer! Just tried this in the console and works just right. You learn something new every day! :)

Comment: 2 years later and still a useful answer.

Comment: 3 years later , and it fixed my problem also

Comment: 4 yrs later :-)

Comment: 5 years later, what am i even doing here.

Comment: 6 years later ...

Comment: 7 years later .

Comment: This returns `Invalid Date` in Safari :(

Comment: 8 years later .

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Solution from [UTC Date Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s).
Which basicall does the following:

```
console.log(new Date("2014-12-23"));
console.log(convertDateToUTC(new Date("2014-12-23")));

function convertDateToUTC(date) { 
return new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds()); 
}
```

The output would be like that in the console (for me at least :D)

Tue Dec 23 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)

 Tue Dec 23 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)

Answer (score -1):

use setFullYear the syntax is Date.setFullYear(year,month,day)

```
mydate = new Date();
mydate.setFullYear(2016, 08, 05);
```