# JS date is not giving proper output

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am passing YYYY-MM-DD-hrs-min-sec as arguments in my node js application and getting wrong output,

Here is what I am passing in my nodeJs:

```
console.log("arrivaldateN", new Date("2019-11-25T15:48:43.14"))
//Op => 2019-11-25T10:18:43.140Z
console.log("arrivaldateN", new Date(2019, 10, 25, 15, 48,43))
// op => 2019-11-25T10:18:43.140Z
```

My expected output is like this `2019-11-25T15:48:43.140Z` 
here I got wrong hrs and mins in node js Date object.

while doing the same thing in chrome console and it will give me correct output

```
> new Date(2019, 10, 25, 15, 48,43)
> Mon Nov 25 2019 15:48:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

is there anything wrong in the provided code?

Comment: This is an ISO date 2019-11-25T15:48:43.14 and you are creating new date from that. In chrome you are using new Date and passing a non ISO format. What is your final expected output?

Comment: In what way is it the wrong output?

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth  I want same output as chrome giving me like `2019-11-25T15:48:43.140Z`

Comment: @Nick In first way

Comment: Chrome is just doing the `toString()` for you. Try `console.log((new Date("2019-11-25T15:48:43.14")).toString())` output (in Adelaide) is `Mon Nov 25 2019 15:48:43 GMT+1030 (Australian Central Daylight Time)`

Comment: @Nick yes that's fine. how can I get output like `2019-11-25T15:48:43.140Z` this ?

Comment: You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223481/incorrect-date-shown-in-new-date-in-javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toISOString()` function.

The `toISOString()` method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ or ±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ, respectively). The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

```
let arrivaldateN=new Date(2019, 10, 25, 10, 48,43);

console.log(arrivaldateN.toISOString());
```

Comment: right, but how can I get output like 2019-11-25T15:48:43.140Z this?

Comment: toISOString() is giving same output as I mentioned in question

Comment: Kindly edit your question and list out clearly what is your input date and what is your expected output. Its really confusing.

Comment: I updated my question, please check if you need more explanation then I can provide.