# JavaScript getWeekNumber setting a UK timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I'm having some issues with getting the week number. I need to get the week number with the week starting with Sunday and with a UK timezone. If a client is accessing the website internationally the week number is different because of the timezone.

The code:

```js
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
  var d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate()));
  d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() - d.getUTCDay());
  var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1));
  return Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
};

function getWeekNum(dateStr) {
    var date = new Date(dateStr);
    var currentWeekNumber = date.getWeek();
    return currentWeekNumber;
}

console.log(getWeekNum("2023-03-19"));
```

Here are the differences between UK and Cancun

[image]

My Question is: How do I set it so it only uses the UK Time Zone? If its not possible with JavaScript could anyone point me to a PHP script that does the exact same thing?

Thank you!

Richard

Comment: i think mine is wrong. it confused me enough already i removed it sorry. maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403486/add-or-subtract-timezone-difference-to-javascript-date will also help

Comment: There are a number of issues here. Firstly, what is the format of *dateStr*? The use of the *Date* constructor to parse the timestamp means "2023-03-19" and "03/19/2023" will represent different moments in time and possibly different weeks. Also, the method of determining the week number is not consistent with ISO 8601 or some other methods of numbering weeks. It means that for a particular year, weeks start on whatever day 1 January falls on which might be any day of the week. It also means leap years will have different week numbering to other years even when 1 January is the same weekday.

Answer (score 0):

Since the input to your computation is a date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, the computation involves only whole days and no times of day. It can therefore be carried out without reference to the UK time zone or indeed any time zone.

Avoid using `new Date(...)` with numeric arguments, which always gives something in the local time zone. Instead, use only `new Date("YYYY-MM-DD")` which always gives you midnight in UTC.

```js
function getWeekNum(dateStr) {
  var d = new Date(dateStr);
  d.setDate(d.getUTCDate() - d.getUTCDay());
  var yearStart = new Date(d.getUTCFullYear() + "-01-01");
  return Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
}
```

Comment: Timezone does matter. While YYYY-MM-DD is parsed as UTC, this answer then uses local values. For a place with negative offset, 2023-04-02 (Sunday) will be parsed to a local date of 2023-04-01 (Saturday), so the previous week if the start of the week is Sunday (per the OP). You should also check with the OP that the input is actually YYYY-MM-DD, that may just be an example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I have corrected my answer to use the UTC functions. `new Date("2023-04-06").getUTCDate()` gives 6 when executed in a Google Apps Script project running in the New York time zone.